# Schwache Verben und starke Verben

Tags: verb, conjugation, past-participle, rule-of-thumb

Im Deutschen gibt es bei Verben eine Unterteilung zwischen *starken* und *schwachen Verben*. Je nachdem zu welcher Gruppe ein Wort gehört, wird das Partizip II unterschiedlich gebildet.

1. Schwaches Verb: *bezahlen* (Infinitiv) → *bezahlt* (Partizip II)
2. Starkes Verb: *bekommen* (Infinitiv) → *bekommen* (Partizip II)

Man muss also wissen, zu welcher Gruppe ein Verb gehört, damit man das richtige Partizip bilden kann, wenn man die ganzen unregelmäßigen Verben mal außen vor lässt.

Gibt es eine Daumenregel, über die man einem Verb "ansehen" kann, zu welcher Gruppe es gehört?

Comment: Die Faustregel lautet in jeder Sprache: Je häufiger das Wort, desto unregelmäßiger die Konjugation.

Comment: Tja, die einfachste Regel ist eben doch "Alles ist unregelmäßig" :)

Comment: Wegen mir ; )) gibt's da einen Unterschied, ob es aktives oder passives Handeln ist. Ich habe ihn bepfeift. Er wurde bepfiffen. Oder ?
U"brigens, in Norddeutschland ein "er" backt Brot; in Su"ddeutschland er ba"ckt. Im Su"den wird das Brot gebacken, im Norden eher gebackt : ))

Comment: Die Faustregel ist: Je älter ein Verb ist, desto eher wird es per Ablaut (=stark, unregelmäßig) konjugiert; je jünger es ist, desto eher wird es per Dentalsuffix (=schwach, regelmäßig) konjugiert. Verben, die direkt aus dem Indogermanischen stammen, sind also eher stark; Verben, die erst in germanischer Zeit gebildet wurden, sind eher schwach. Mit etwas Intuition kann man abschätzen, dass "kommen" ein ganz altes Wort ist, das direkt aus dem Indogermanischen stammt (=> stark); "bezahlen" dagegen ist jünger und vom Wort "Zahl" abgeleitet (=> schwach)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mir ist keine derartige Regel bekannt. Darüber hinaus befürchte ich, dass das nicht (zumindest nicht zuverlässig) funktionieren würde, weil es praktisch gleich geschriebene Wörter gibt, die unterschiedlichen Klassen angehören. Starke Verben sind zwar nicht dasselbe wie unregelmäßige - werden heutzutage jedoch häufig gleichgesetzt, weil es sehr viele Ausnahmen gibt. "bekommen" wird übrigens von zwei Wörterbüchern, in denen ich nachschaute, als unregelmäßig gekennzeichnet und ist damit nicht "regelmäßig stark".

Canoo unterscheidet deshalb beispielsweise nur regelmäßig und unregelmäßig, nicht stark und schwach. Davon abgesehen unterscheidet sich streng genommen stark und schwach nicht nur durch die Bildung der Endung des Perfekt-Partizips, sondern vor allem in der Frage, ob der *Wortstamm* bei der Flexion geändert wird oder nicht, sprich, ob das Verb *stark genug* ist, die Stammform zu ändern. Selbst wenn man weiß, dass es stark genug ist, gibt es noch mehrere Klassen von starken Verben, die wiederum unterschiedlich ihre Partizipien bilden. Abgesehen davon, dass man natürlich sowieso noch auf die unzähligen unregelmäßigen hereinfallen kann.

Beispiel:

- backen, buk, gebacken bzw. backen, backte, gebacken
- packen, packte, gepackt

Backen ist ein schönes Beispiel. War es früher stark (geänderter Stamm), ist es heute schwach im Präteritum - dennoch endet das Partizip auf en, wie ursprünglich nur bei starken Verben. Achtung: Nicht verwechseln mit dem regelmäßig schwach gebeugten Verb *backen, backte, gebackt* (festkleben). Die Existenz desselben zeigt, wie kompliziert die Geschichte ist.

- lügen, log, gelogen
- pflügen, pflügte, gepflügt

Die Infinitive sehen sich jeweils sehr ähnlich - die Flexion ist jedoch unterschiedlich.
Eventuell kann man da über die Wortherkunft noch etwas finden - aber wenn man die kennt, kann man auch wissen, welcher Klasse das Verb angehört.

Nicht umsonst lernt man Verben häufig mit genau diesen drei Formen.

Comment: +1 für das schöne Backen-Beispiel. Wenn die Formen nicht ständig im Wandel wären, wär der Spaß einfacher... immerhin kann ich mich an genug Diskussionen unter Muttersprachlern erinnern, welche Form denn richtig sei, dass es nicht mal die 100%ig zu wissen scheinen. Ich sage nur: es schneit, es schnie, es hat geschnotten! ;)

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort. Schade, dass es keine einfachen Regeln gibt. Ich hätte meiner Kollegin, die gerade Deutsch lernen muss, gern geholfen. Den Hinweis, die Verben immer in den drei Formen zu lernen, habe ich aber weitergegeben.

Comment: @ladybug: "schneien, schnie, geschnotten" werde ich jetzt so lange benutzen, bis es im Duden steht ;-)

Comment: Als grobe Unterteilung der starken Verben gibt es die ablautenden und die ehemals reduplizierenden Verben (cf. lat. currere, cucurri; im gotischen noch vorhanden, im ahd. ist die Reduplikation aber schon verschwunden). Z.B.: leiden/litt/gelitten, reiten/ritt/geritten, pfeifen/pfiff/gepfiffen, aber: meiden/mied/gemieden.

Answer (score 7):

Dieser Frage und anderen ähnlichen hat der berühmte Linguist Steven Pinker ein Buch gewidmet:*Words and Rules*.
Das achte Kapitel ist besonders relevant: *The Horrors of the German Language*. Aber beruhigt Euch, liebe Deutschprachige, es ist eine Anspielung auf einen satirischen Text von Mark Twain und ist "tongue in cheek", nicht böse, gemeint!
Mit deutschen Kollegen hat Pinker Experimente angestellt und festgestellt, dass es grossen Einstimmigkeit  gab in der Bildung des Partizips nichtexistierender, erfundener  Verben. Für ""bepfeifen", zum Beispiel, entschied sich die  Mehrheit für "bepfeift" eher als für "bepfiffen".
 Das beweist, laut Pinker und seiner Kollegen, dass Unregelmässigkeiten nicht so willkürlich sind, wie man denken könnte.
Ich kann das Buch jedem, der sich für Sprachen interessiert nicht  stark genug empfehlen.

Comment: +1 für das Buch. Für die Interessierten: Der satirische Text von Mark Twain ist [The Awful German Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_German_Language). Dass die Unregelmäßigkeiten nicht so willkürlich sind, wird übrigens häufig als unterschiedliche Klassen beschrieben, deren Regeln sich historisch herleiten lassen, die aber zu komplex sind, um sie im Kopf zu halten.