# "Bäckt" or "backt"?

Tags: verb, conjugation

In Dreyer/Schmitt, "bäckt" is given as the primary third-person form of "backen". Since I never used this and have not heard it often where I live (Northern Germany), I was very surprised by this and wondered if this could be right. Are both forms still equally valid? Are there regional differences?

Comment: Here in Franconia "bäckt" is used almost exclusively.

Comment: Additional to the answer check the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/backen_herstellen_garen). The alternatives are mentioned.

Comment: Wer oder was ist Dreyer/Schmitt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both forms are equally valid. The differences are regional in use, not in meaning. I did find that "backt" is sometimes listed as the more informal of the two, but that may again be regional. Both forms can be used equally, as opposed to something like "buk" (rather dated or extremely formal) vs "backte" (standard) for the past tense.

Comment: +1, though "buk" is fine even today, and it's a great example for [an older form that has evolved from strong to weak](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/1684/155).