# Past participle ending in -t versus -en

Tags: past-participle

I must relearn some of the more basic parts of German (especially the different aspects of verbs.)

Is there any helpful method, pattern or rule to memorizing when the past participle ends in *‑t* versus *‑en*?

If not, I would even settle for a well-formulated online introduction to this topic, so that I can refresh my German.

Comment: Related German question about the past participle: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/schwache-verben-und-starke-verben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between **strong** (past participle with **‑en**) and **weak** (past participle with **‑t**) verbs is that strong verbs constitute a relatively small, closed class, whereas the number of the weak verbs is large and always growing. This is because new verbs inflect weakly: *gemanagt, gebloggt, gedopt, gebootet, getwittert*.

The overwhelming majority of weak verbs inflect completely regularly; preterite and past participle are both formed with **‑t**.

> leben, leb**t**e, geleb**t**
> warten, wart**et**e, gewart**et**

Two common irregular weak verbs are *bringen* and *denken*. These have a different stem in past forms.

> **denk**en, **dach**te, ge**dach**t
> **bring**en, **brach**te, ge**brach**t

Then there are **Rückumlautverben** ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCckumlaut)) and **modal verbs** (**Präteritopräsentien**, [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4teritopr%C3%A4sens)), which show a different vowel.

> n**e**nnen, n**a**nnte, gen**a**nnt
> m**ü**ssen, m**u**sste, gem**u**sst

Strong verbs always have alternating vowels known as **Ablaut** (see  [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starkes_Verb)). These must be memorised. The ending is **-en** in the past participle; the preterite has no ending.

> s**e**hen, s**a**h, ges**e**hen
> k**o**mmen, k**a**m, gek**o**mmen
> f**i**nden, f**a**nd, gef**u**nden
> n**e**hmen, n**a**hm, gen**o**mmen
> schr**ei**ben, schr**ie**b, geschr**ie**ben

There are lists of strong and irregular weak verbs all over the Internet, for instance on [deutschlernerblog.de](https://deutschlernerblog.de/1100-unregelmaessige-und-starke-deutsche-verben-nach-sprachniveau-a1-c2/). What's great about that page is that there are several different lists for different [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels) levels. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_unregelm%C3%A4%C3%9Figer_Verben_im_Deutschen) has an overview over the different kinds of irregular verbs. (They also have their own [list of strong verbs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_starker_Verben_(deutsche_Sprache)), but grouping them into *Ablautklassen* is useful only for historical purposes and not for language learners.)

**Recommended strategy:** Start memorising strong and irregular weak verbs and assume that every other verb is weak and regular.

Note that derived verbs usually follow their base. So if you have correctly memorised *weisen, wies, gewiesen*, you also know how *aufweisen, beweisen, hinweisen, verweisen, vorweisen* etc. are formed. This is how the list linked above gets from 170 strong and irregular verbs to 1100.

> w**ei**sen, w**ie**s, gew**ie**sen
> aufw**ei**sen, w**ie**s auf, aufgew**ie**sen
> bew**ei**sen, bew**ie**s, bew**ie**sen
> …

However, beware of homophones!

> fehlen, fehl**t**e, gefehl**t** *(weak)*
> bef**e**hlen, bef**a**hl, bef**oh**len *(strong)*

Comment: Thank you and I apologize if my question is too close to the related question that was already answered. Both your answer and the link were helpful.

Comment: Also learn, that für a few words there are regional differences: In most parts of Germany: *»Der Fernseher ist eingeschalt**et.** Sie hat die Suppe versalz**t.** Der Kerl ist abgehau**en** und hat dabei **gewinkt.**«* But in Austria: *»Der Fernseher ist eingeschalt**en.** Sie hat die Suppe versalz**en.** Der Kerl ist abgehau**t** und hat dabei **gewunken.**«*

Comment: @Hubert _"Sie hat die Suppe versalzt."_ seriously? That should always be _"Sie hat die Suppe versalzen."_